# How do I write a multi-line message to the quickfix or location list?

Tags: vimscript, functions, quickfix, encoding

I've got a program that spits out multi-line messages separated with something other than a newline. I want these messages to show in the quickfix and location lists spanning multiple lines as intended. What character can I replace the separator with to get that result? For example, `setqflist([{'text': "1\r2"}])` prints `1^M2` on a single line. What character can I use to get two lines?

Answer (score 1):

It can depend on your system. Some characters may be right on one system and not work at all on another. Between Macintosh, Windows, and Unix/Linux, there are three different types of carriage returns.

`\n` may work for you. You could also try them both together: `\n\r` (I think that's the right way, but you could also try it reversed)

Alternately, you can instruct Vim to use a particular kind of carriage return, no matter what system you are on, by playing with the `fileformat` (abbreviated as `ff`) option:

`set ff=dos` for example switches to the Windows formatting when it reads the file or buffer. You can re-read a file you already have open in a different format by using this command:

```
:e ++ff=unix
```

You may have to play around with it and see what works best.

For far more detail, see [this page](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/File_format) on the Vim wiki.